# Check box not appearing in checked text view in Android when any RTL (Ex: Arabic) language is selected

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have a CheckedTextBox view in my layout. When the locale selected is English, text appears at the Left side and Check box at the right side and everything works fine.

But when i selected the locale as Arabic, Arabic strings are getting displayed at the right but check box is not displaying either at the left or right.

Did any one face similar issue, please let me know the solution if any one knows.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet so I am entering this here.  Make sure your layout_width is not being affected by the 'size' of the arabic text.  i.e. if you are using a certain layout_width and it works with english, arabic for example might require a different point size.  Something to consider...

Comment: I am using layout_width as match_parent

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with you, sometimes the checkbox was missing. I found that setting `singleLine` to `false` (and in my case, `maxlines = 2` as well) did the trick.

Which version of Android do you use?